# 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am struggling to find the solution to my error for my project, can someone please assist me and show me the correct way.

Here is my code:

```
$productkey = $_SESSION['key'];
  $productuser = $_SESSION['user'];
  $productemail = $_SESSION['email'];
// Include Database Connection
require 'assets/sys/config.php';
$query = dbConnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO _system (_product_key, _product_user, _product_email, _site_email, _site_title) VALUES (:_product_key, :_product_user, :_product_email, :_site_title, :site_email)");
    $query->bindParam(':_product_key', $productkey);
    $query->bindParam(':_product_user', $productuser);
    $query->bindParam(':_product_email', $productemail);
    $query->bindParam(':_site_title', $_POST['sitetitle']);
    $query->bindParam(':_site_email', $_POST['siteemail']);
    $query->execute();
```

Error I am receiving:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in
```

Comment: Do you have a session_start(); in the begining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your bound parameters. `:site_email` instead of `:_site_email`.

By the way... You know you can do that with a simple hash array, right? Just name the keys the same as the placeholders in the query.

Comment: It happens to all of us. Last time I spent 4 hours on some problem before realizing I made a typo right at the beginning... :(

Answer (score 1):

In your query you have:

```
:site_email
```

But you do bind this:

```
$query->bindParam(':_site_email', $_POST['siteemail']);
```

Those are different, edit with:

```
$query->bindParam(':site_email', $_POST['siteemail']);
```

Or change the parameter on your sql.

Comment: thanks! after a couple of hours i need to check for typo`s ;)

Comment: It happens, remember (by the way) that you can specify on bindparam the type of var, example numeric or string =) it can help with security

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there's the typo. But you also have `_site_email` and `_site_title` in the wrong order so you won't be inserting the data where you expect.

Should be:

```
$query = dbConnect()->prepare("INSERT INTO _system (_product_key, _product_user, _product_email, _site_title, _site_email) 
VALUES (:_product_key, :_product_user, :_product_email, :_site_title, :_site_email)");
```